# Разница в браузерах

Tags: css

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема: меню сайта в Opera выглядит нормально, а вот в Chrome и Mozilla сверху отступ какой-то. Помогите решить проблему, пожалуйста. Можете взглянуть: mp3axtar.com.

Comment: Для начала перенеси все все META, TITLE, LINK и SCRIPT из BODY в HEAD

Comment: Не знаю, почему так все говорят, но они тат и так в `head` находятся.

Comment: Тогда это как??? http://s49.radikal.ru/i125/1110/40/b4a5112ee8b4.jpg

Comment: не знаю дажн а вот что я вижу темболее не на всоём компьютере http://i027.radikal.ru/1110/d4/91df9d0429ba.jpg

Comment: Интересно получается "огненный жук" и исходный код "огненной лисы" разные вещи показывают

Answer (score 1):

Возможно дело в том, что в ваших шаблонах используется [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark):

`$ curl -s http://mp3axtar.com/ | less`

```
<U+FEFF><U+FEFF><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
/* ... */
</head>
<body>
    <U+FEFF>    <div id="header">
```

Попробуйте пересохранить шаблоны без BOM.

Comment: Да я тоже так думаю это случилось после того как я внёс изменение в скрипте открыв файл на самом сервере блокнотом

Comment: Да, блокнот любит пихать BOM куда ни попадя.

Answer (score 0):

Уберите закрывающий `</head>` сразу же после открывающего! А то структура `DOM` чёрти какая...

Comment: Нормально всё вроде бы:

    <head>
    <title>mp3axtar.com - onlayn mp3 dinlə, endir, paylaş</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
    </head>

Comment: Что-то меня утром с просоня бес попутал. Но откройте отладчик и смотрите: все мета-таги и подключаемые скрипты - в разделе боди, а не в хеад! Копайте в эту сторону.

Comment: Пользуйся фаерБагом от мозилы.

Comment: знакомая картина, вчера переписывал мету, после этого первый див div уплыл на 1 строку вниз. решилось "методом научного тыка"